# How do I read weapon / armor stats in ADOM?

Tags: adom

For example, I know that:

- Armors: [+dv, +pv].
- Weapons: (+hc, dmg) where dmg is something like 1d4.

How about missile weapon and missiles?
Where can I find a information about these? I can't find them in the manual / guidebook / wiki because I don't know what they're called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same as melee weapons. The projectile itself will list the accuracy and die damage, while a launcher (e.g. bow) provides to-hit and damage bonuses, displayed in that order.